# Finding the covariance of two discrete random variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have two discrete random variavles; $X$ and $Y$ with:

[image]

And I want to calculate $Cov(Y,Y+e^X)$, and I've tried the following:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = EmpiricalDistribution[{1/8, 2/8, 5/8} -> {1, 2, 3}];
\[ScriptCapitalD]1 = EmpiricalDistribution[{1/5, 4/5} -> {-1, 1}];
Covariance[\[ScriptCapitalD]1, \[ScriptCapitalD]1 + e^\[ScriptCapitalD]]
```

But this doesnt return any value, what am I doing wrong?

I have also tried calculating stuff like $P(X=3,Y=1)$ and $P(X\cdot Y \geq 2)$ without any luck

Comment: And $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Yes, they are, forgot to mention.

Comment: This isn't a fix of your problem, but you should be aware that there's no such thing as `e`; there's `E` - _Mathematica_ is case sensitive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This solution uses built-in functions :

```
dx = EmpiricalDistribution[{1/8, 2/8, 5/8} -> {1, 2, 3}];
dy = EmpiricalDistribution[{1/5, 4/5} -> {-1, 1}];
Covariance[
 TransformedDistribution[{y, y + Exp[x]}, {x \[Distributed] dx, 
   y \[Distributed] dy}], 1, 2]
(* 16/25 *)
```

Answer (score 5):

To calculate these kinds of expressions, use `Expectation`:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = EmpiricalDistribution[{1/8, 2/8, 5/8} -> {1, 2, 3}];
\[ScriptCapitalD]1 = EmpiricalDistribution[{1/5, 4/5} -> {-1, 1}];

mu = Expectation[Exp[x], x \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]]
mu1 = Expectation[y, y \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]1]

Expectation[(y - mu1) (y + Exp[x] - mu1 - mu), {x \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD], y \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]1}]
```

Comment: *Mathematica* 10.4.1 needs a `Simplify` or `Expand` applied to the last line to simplify to the answer of 16/25.